# Replacement for WebSecurity and DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler when using XML configuration

Tags: xml, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

In past Spring projects, when I had configured Spring Security by Java configuration classes, this method would be added to configure security in the web pages:

```java
  @Override
  public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
      DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler handler = new DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler();
      handler.setPermissionEvaluator(permissionEvaluator);
      web.expressionHandler(handler);
}
```

the configuration class was a subclass from `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`.

In my more recent project, I am using XML configuration, and I do not found how configure this same subject using XML. Someone can give a hint of how to do that?

ps.: my current XML configuration for Spring Security:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
        xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">  
    <security:http pattern="/" security="none"></security:http>

    <security:http pattern="/css/**" security="none"></security:http>

    <security:http pattern="/img/**" security="none"></security:http>

    <security:http pattern="/js/**" security="none"></security:http>
    <security:http pattern="/c/**" security="none"></security:http>
    <security:http pattern="/p/**" security="none"></security:http>
    <security:http pattern="/page/**" security="none"></security:http>

    <security:http use-expressions="true" auto-config="true">
        <security:form-login login-page="/signin"
            login-processing-url="/login" username-parameter="login"
            password-parameter="senha" default-target-url="/"
            always-use-default-target="true" />
        <security:logout logout-url="/logout"
            delete-cookies='JSESSIONID' logout-success-url="/" />
        <security:remember-me key="remember-me"
            remember-me-parameter="remember-me" remember-me-cookie="remember-me" />
        <security:csrf disabled="true" />
    </security:http>

    <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService">
            <security:password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder"></security:password-encoder>
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <bean id="userDetailsService" class="org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.jdbc.JdbcDaoImpl">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
        <property name="usersByUsernameQuery" value="select login, senha, enabled from usuario where login = ?"></property>
        <property name="authoritiesByUsernameQuery" value="SELECT t1.username, t2.authority FROM (SELECT u.login as username, c.nome as credencial FROM usuario u, usuario_credencial uc, credencial c WHERE u.id = uc.usuario_id and c.id = uc.credenciais_id) as t1 INNER JOIN (SELECT c.nome as credencial, a.nome as authority FROM credencial c, credencial_autorizacao ca, autorizacao a WHERE c.id = ca.credencial_id and a.id = ca.autorizacoes_id) as t2 ON t1.credencial = t2.credencial WHERE t1.username = ?;"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="passwordEncoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder">
        <constructor-arg name="strength" value="4"></constructor-arg></bean>
    <bean id="expressionHandler" class="org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler">
        <property name="permissionEvaluator" ref="permissionEvaluator"></property></bean>
    <bean id="permissionEvaluator" class="org.kleber.MyPermissionEvaluator"></bean>
</beans>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Spring Security Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#nsa-expression-handler):

> **41.1.20 <expression-handler>**
>
> Defines the `SecurityExpressionHandler` instance which will be used if expression-based access-control is enabled. A default implementation (with no ACL support) will be used if not supplied.
>
> **Parent Elements of <expression-handler>**
>
> - global-method-security
> - http
> - websocket-message-broker
>
> **<expression-handler> Attributes**
>
> - **ref** Defines a reference to a Spring bean that implements `SecurityExpressionHandler`.